# How to set npm not to install packages that had been installed globally?

Tags: npm

My project references `mocha`, `phantomjs`, etc, which takes a lot of time to download during `npm install`. This is not a problem in my local machine because I only download them once and can use them forever unless I decide to manually upgrade them.

However, in my `CI` machine, my `jenkins` server need to download them every time that I did a `git commit` and `git push` to do the testing and deploy.

So can I just speed up that process by set the npm not to download these slow packages from the remote server? Rather, install them from local cache or not to install them if I installed them globally?

Anyone knows how to configure that?

Answer (score 1):

I [found some packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=npm+install) that might be helpful

- [npm-install-changed](https://github.com/oNaiPs/npm-install-changed) will run `npm install` only if the contents of `package.json`'s `devDependencies` and `dependencies` were changed, note that it assumes that `node_modules` persists across different builds which might not be helpful if your CI server always start from scratch
- [npm-install-cache](https://github.com/kapetan/npm-install-cache/blob/master/npm-install-cache.sh) runs `npm install` and then copies your current `node_modules` folder (to somewhere in `\tmp`), if you call the script again it will verify **any changes to package.json** (instead of changes done on `devDependencies` or `dependencies`), if it didn't change then it will copy the `node_modules` folder stored in `\tmp`, the only limitation I see is that it's not cross platform and that the cache folder is `\tmp` which is erased on reboot (or maybe even when a is process finished!)

The second package might not work as it is but it seems like a good place to start :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify all of the packages you want to use locally in `devDependencies` in package.json, and then running `npm install -d` will install those instead of the main dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I had put them in `devDependencies`. The headache is the `npm install` those packages are very slow so I hope I can install them once and then I can use them forever.